Executing async Task every n seconds, including the runtime of the Task itself
I have a windows service, in which I want to execute a asynchronous task every n seconds, but the time the task I am waiting for should be included in this n seconds.
Here is a short sample
CancellationToken stoppingToken = new();
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await DoJob();
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}

and here the DoJob Task:
private async Task DoJob()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}

If I log the loop and the Task I can see, that the task is taking 3 seconds, and the delay afterwards 5 seconds.
Loop startet at 07.06.2024 12:01:46
Start Job at    07.06.2024 12:01:46
Ended Job at    07.06.2024 12:01:49 
Loop startet at 07.06.2024 12:01:54 
Start Job at    07.06.2024 12:01:54 
Ended Job at    07.06.2024 12:01:57 
Loop startet at 07.06.2024 12:02:02 
Start Job at    07.06.2024 12:02:02 
Ended Job at    07.06.2024 12:02:05 

How can I change this to run the task every 5 seconds INLCUDING the 3 seconds the task takes. (Of cause in real world the time the task takes is not known exactly.
And in a second step: how to check if the previous task has ended to avoid start it multiple times. (E.g. the task takes 10 seeconds an the delay is only 5 seconds ...)

Simply don't await DoJob? Just put the returned Task into a variable and after the delay when you want to start that again check if it isn't still running. Decide what todo in that case. When you don't await like I'm proposing check in your real world example your exception handling that needs then to change.

Sidenote don't use Thread.Sleep in Task based code. Always use Task.Delay.

If you want the time, use DateTime.Now. If you want to repeat something periodically, use a Timer. Tasks aren't scheduler tasks and have no notion of time.

Don't always use Task.Delay, but always avoid Thread.Sleep. Task.Delay itself uses a timer object internally. Calling it multiple times creates multiple Timer objects that need to be garbage-collected. If you want to do something every 5 seconds, use a System.Threading.Timer with a period of 5s

What if DoJob takes longer than 5 seconds, is that OK?

Related: Run async method regularly with specified interval.

You need to figure out if it is ok to have multiple DoJobs running concurrently, if it is ok, use Timers.Timer or Threading.Timer, if it is not ok, use a PeriodicTimer.

I casted a reopen and then a close vote because I thought that the linked question was not a duplicate, and then I saw that I was wrong.

Look at quite new PeriodicTimer
var periodicTimer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

while (await periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
{
    await DoJob();    
}


The easiest way to run and schedule jobs is by using a library like Quartz.net of Hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io).
With this libraries you can create a job with a cron expression to trigger the job on specific times or time intervals.
You can also disable concurrent execution of the jobs in this libraries.
If you want to do it yourself and not use a library, you should calculate the length of the execution of the task. This execution time is subtracted from the default waittime.
var intervalMilliseconds = 5000;
CancellationToken stoppingToken = new();
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    if (!isTaskRunning)
    {
        isTaskRunning = true;
        var taskStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        await DoJob();
        var taskEndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        isTaskRunning = false;

        var elapsedTime = (taskEndTime - taskStartTime).TotalMilliseconds;               
        var remainingDelay = intervalMilliseconds - elapsedTime;

        if (remainingDelay > 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay((int)remainingDelay, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await Task.Delay(intervalMilliseconds, stoppingToken);
    } 
}



Yes but it feels like you are proposing a chainsaw where scissors might be sufficient.

Updated my answer without using a library, but calculating the remaining delay

@Ralf are you sure? Task.Delay is inappropriate for repeated usage because it uses a new Timer object each time. A Timer object itself is suitable only for simple operations. There's no reason to calculate the remaining delay at all for those simple operations though, just using a Timer is enough

@PanagiotisKanavos I was but wasn't aware of the implementation details of Task.Delay. Will have a look at the code if there is something in there i should know.

Don't use the DateTime.UtcNow for measuring time intervals. Your solution becomes susceptible to system-wise clock adjustments. Use the Stopwatch class instead.
